# get_template_directory_uri cached?

Tags: site-url

I'm having a little problem with a wordpress installation. Basically, I have two servers: `test.dev` and `staging.dev`.

Set up (using the hosts file) and I've just copied the `test.dev` WordPress installation over to the staging server. Works brilliant on my computer but on someone who doesn't have `test.dev` none of the CSS or images load. I looked into it and every path is still referencing `test.dev`. I have this function in `functions.php`:

```
function route_static_path($path)
{
    echo get_template_directory_uri()."/".$path;
    return true;
}
```

I thought the value for `get_template_directory_uri()` might be set in `wp-config.php` but it's not. I'm really confused as to where this is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Caching is not your problem here. The home URL and site URL are stored in the `wp_options` table in your database. You can update them either by visiting the *Settings > General* page in your WordPress dashboard, or you can edit the `siteurl` and `home` option values directly in the database through an SQL query or a client such as phpMyAdmin.

You can also override any site or home URL option stored in the database by [adding the following code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) to your `wp-config.php` file:

```
 define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
 define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

The above code will adjust depending on your domain.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear this setting is for some reason stored in the database. I just ran this query:

```
UPDATE `wp_options`
SET `option_value`='http://staging.dev'
WHERE `option_name`='siteurl'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a site migration problem. You need to everything that refers to `test.dev` to now be `staging.dev` in the database. You can use this script to help you with this task: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon the same issue. Although I replaced the URL in all .php files and in the table `options` (siteurl and home), Chrome console still said that I try to load theme resources from another domain. I checked my database and found a cache option. I deleted it from my database. Wordpress then creates a new entry using the updated `siteurl` from database.

```
DELETE FROM options WHERE option_name = 'us_theme_options_css';
```